# Printing to a file from user input multiple lines?

Tags: java, file, filewriter

I am trying to write a program that asks the user to pu in the name of a limerick they would like to save, then it creates a file with the name of that limerick and then asks them to write the limerick, which will then be saved to file. I have this code to creae the file, ut when i try to write the limerick to the file it seems to get caught in a loop and continualy wite the first line entered to the file. Any help would be very much appreciated?

```
public void start () {
    System.out.println("<<THIS PROGRAM SAVES A LIMERICK THAT YOU HAVE WROTE>>");
}    

public File create () {
    System.out.println("<<ENTER THE NAME OF THE LIMERICK>>");
    name = scan.nextLine();
    nameFile = name + ".txt";
    File file = new File(nameFile);
    try {
        if (file.createNewFile() ) {
            System.out.println("<<FILE CREATED>>");
        } else {
            System.out.println("<<FILE ALREADY EXISTS>>");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return file;
}

public void write () {
    Limerick write = new Limerick();
    File file = write.create();
    System.out.println("<<ENTER THE LIMIRICK>>");
    PrintWriter pw;
    try {
        pw = new PrintWriter (new BufferedWriter (new FileWriter(file)));
        limerick = scan.nextLine();
        while (!(limerick.equals("DONE"))) {
            pw.println(limerick);
        }
        pw.close();
        System.out.println("<<LIMERICK WRITTEN TO FILE>>");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}

public static void main (String args[]) {       
    Limerick method = new Limerick();
    method.start();
    method.write();

}
```

Comment: The value of `limerick` should change inside the  `while (!(limerick.equals("DONE")))` loop, or it will be an infinite loop (e.g put `limerick = scan.nextLine();` inside the loop).

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following loop the value of limerick is never updated and hence it goes into an infinite loop

```
while (!(limerick.equals("DONE"))) {
    pw.println(limerick);
}
```

Change it to something like this :

```
while (!(limerick.equals("DONE"))) {
    pw.println(limerick);
    limerick = scan.nextLine();
}
```

Thereby after each iteration the value of `limerick` is updated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run `scan.nextLine()` inside the loop:

```
    while (!((limerick = scan.nextLine()).equals("DONE"))) {
        pw.println(limerick);
    }
```